# How can a button press draw on canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to draw a rectangle when the user presses a button in Javascript. If the code in the script is not in a function, it draws the rectangle but of course doesn't respond to the button. If I put it in a function called by the button, nothing happens whether it's in the head or the body. How can I draw the rectangle with the button press?

Many thanks in advance!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test 4</title>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="600">
        <p>Fallback content for browsers that don't support the canvas tag.</p>
    </canvas>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            const canvas = document.querySelector('.myCanvas');
            const width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            const height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
            ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 150);
        }
    </script>

    <p>
        Click the button
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query selector to `#myCanvas`.

A prefix of `.` indicates it should find an element with a class of `myCanvas`, to search instead for an element id use the `#` prefix.